# Infura: "project ID request rate exceeded" despite minimal requests

Tags: infura

Looks like I'm being rate limited by Infura, despite making nowhere near the 100,000 request/day limit under Infura's Core plan. `truffle migrate` and `truffle test` both produce `VM Exception while processing transaction: Error: Returned error: Returned error: project ID request rate exceeded`. I even created a new Infura project and used that new project ID, but received the very same message. So, is it my fault? All I'm doing is `ganache-cli --fork https://kovan.infura.io/v3/[api_key]@latest -u [address]` followed by `truffle test`. What's the remedy?

[image]

Comment: I think this is more of an Infura commercial support question than something the community can help with. If you need an alternative for Infura try https://quiknode.io/

Comment: I don't think the problem is that you are making too many queries but you are making them too fast. The daily rate gives be around 70 request per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael from Infura here, please email me at michael@infura.io and I will work this out with you. As Ismail said, it has to do with a short burst of requests, we are working with Truffle to best tune how it interacts with RPC calls during deploys.

Comment: Any updates? What was the issue?